# get data from 1column and split in to two using based using table join and column filter in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 3 tables:

1. wn_synset(synset_id decimal, w_num decimal, word varchar(255), ss_type char)

This table contains word List in word column.

1. wn_gloss(synset_id decimal, gloss varchar(255)

This table contains meaning(wn_gloss.gloss) of word List of wn_synset table, related with its synset_id column.

1. wn_antony (synset_id_1 decimal, w_num_1 decimal, synset_id_2  decimal, w_num_2 decimal)

This table contains synset_id and w_num of words of opposite of the meaning (corresponding to synset_id and w_num), listed in the same wn_synset.word.

I have joined the wn_synset and wn_gloss using the following code:

```
select      
g.gloss as meaning,
wrd.ss_type as word_Type,
wrd.word as word
FROM wn_synset as wrd 
JOIN  wn_gloss as g
ON wrd.synset_id = g.synset_id 
where wrd.word= 'good'  order by wrd.ss_type
```

Now I want to join the 3rd table wn_antony to have another column having the opposite meaning word.

How could I achieve the following:

```
select      
g.gloss as meaning,
wrd.ss_type as Word_Type,
wrd.word as word
(wrd.word as opposit where wrd.synset_id=tblOpposit.synset_id_2 and wrd.w_num=tblOpposit.w_num_2)

FROM wn_synset as wrd 
JOIN  wn_gloss as g
ON wrd.synset_id = g.synset_id 

join wn_antony as tblOpposit
on wrd.synset_id=tblOpposit.synset_id_1 and wrd.w_num= tblOpposit.w_num_1
where wrd.word= 'good'  order by wrd.ss_type
```

Please help me achieve this. Thanks for any response. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it correctly following should work.

```
select      
    g.gloss as meaning,
    wrd.ss_type as word_Type,
    wrd.word as word,
    wrdopp.word as opposite
FROM wn_synset as wrd 
JOIN  wn_gloss as g
  ON wrd.synset_id = g.synset_id 
JOIN wn_antony as a
  ON a.synset_id_2 = wrd.synset_id
  and wrd.w_num= a.w_num_2 -- Not sure if this is needed
JOIN wn_synset as wrdopp
  ON a.synset_id_1 = wrdopp.synset_id
  and wrdopp.w_num= a.w_num_1 -- Not sure if this is needed
where wrd.word= 'good'  
order by wrd.ss_type
```

Comment: thanks Mr. Adarsh 4 your response...

bttt...t it throws some error as below...
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 34
The multi-part identifier "word.synset_id" could not be bound.... in the line below.

  ON a.synset_id_2 = word.synset_id

Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 35
The multi-part identifier "word.w_num" could not be bound.... in the line below...

  and word.w_num= a.w_num_2 -- Not sure if this is needed

Comment: Updated the query above. There was a typo in table alias. Try it now.

Comment: thanks @AdarshShah
this one worked perfectly...

could u please elaborate the cause of this problem... i too have enconterd with this... and looking for a tutorial.

would you please be so kind to mention the cause or post a link where i can find the detailed solution.

Comment: If you are talking about the typo error with the table alias name you can click on the "edited x hour ago" link and see what I updated. Or you looking for an explanation of the query?